# Finding the bound

Tags: calculus, statistics

$$f(x)=\frac{\pi(1+x^2)(e^{-x^2/2})}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

Anyone knows any tips to find the upper bound for this function? Thank you!

Comment: Where does $x$ live ?

Comment: Hint: Consider $f(x)=(1+x^2)e^{-x^2/2}$ and find its maximum value by using derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Step 0: ignore all constant factors

Step 1: make a change of variables $u=x^2$

Step 2: use the fact that local maxima and minima of a $C^1$ function $f(u)$ are in points where $f'(u)=0$.